# Is Eclipse Oxygen.2 Release (4.7.2) has some major bug as it shows error in throwing Exception using throws keyword

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, eclipse-oxygen

Today I just encountered a problem with **Eclipse Oxygen** that I felt to share it here so that anyone facing same issue can know about it as I searched in Internet but was not able to find anything about it anywhere. So I felt to share the problem that I encountered.

I was learning **Exception Handling** in Java and was practising program of same. When I used *throws* keyword with method to indicate about  *Exception* to its caller method I got an error saying `No exception of type Exception can be thrown; an exception type must be a subclass of Throwable`. However while using *throws* for indicating *Throwable* and *RunTimeException*, there was no any error. It confused me as why *Throwable* is not giving any error but  *Exception* is. Anyhow I made my own conclusion from this, that we cant use *throws* to indicate *Exception*.

I conveyed same thing to one of my Bro and he disagreed with me and we had debate about this, finally he told he will execute and show and I was sure that it will give error, but to my surprise when he executed same piece of code in which I got error, he didn't got any. It surprised me like how this can happen.

Then I came to know there might be some problem with my Eclipse Version so I installed previous version of Eclipse and tried with same piece of code and voila there was no error.

Still I am confused either its my mistake or is this any bug with Eclipse but how there can be bug with release version? So please correct me if I am wrong or something that I don't know.

Screenshot:

[Version: Oxygen.2 Release (4.7.2)
Build id: 20171218-0600](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3p2k.jpg)

[Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)
Build id: 20150219-0600](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPzG8.jpg)

Comment: I feel like this is a configuration issue - I've had Eclipse behave strangely when I don't have the compiler setup - things like it doesn't know about String.  Start by recreating your workspace, especially if you're sharing a single workspace between versions.

Comment: Most likely you have a class called `Exception` which is being picked up instead of `java.lang.Exception`.

Comment: @greg-449 ,thank you  for your reply, I crossed checked with it and Exception class is from `java.lang.Exception`,though its throwing error.

Comment: Cross checked it how?

Comment: In your code replace **...throws Exception...** with **...throws  java.lang.Exception...**, and retest using Oxygen. Does it work? If so then greg-449 is correct. If not then check the Error Log (**Window -> Show View -> Error Log**) for errors.